# can't see inserted collection with meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, meteor

I'm building a data-entry mobile questionnaire using jquery mobile and meteor.

Concept is simple: users enter some information in the questionnaire and validate (insert) with **button**.

My HTML looks like (questionnaire.html, language I'm using may not be too important):

```
<head>
  <title>Questionnaire</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.css" />
  <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>
</head>

    <body>
      {{> insertion }}

    </body>

    <template name="insertion">
      <div data-role="page" id="foo">

       <div data-role="header">
       <h1>MODULE A : RENSEIGNEMENTS SUR LE REPONDANT </h1>
       </div><!-- /header -->
       <div data-role="content">  
       <legend> IDENTIFICATION DU MENAGE </legend> 
       <input autofocus maxlength="12" required placeholder="Entrez un nombre" name="identifiant"  type="number" />                        
       <p> A1. Nom et prénoms du Chef de Ménage:</p>
       <input name="nom_prenom_CM" type="text" />    
       <p> A2. Adresse : </p>
       <input name="adresse" type="text"/>
       <button type="button" class="submit">Insert and continue</button>
       </div><!-- /content -->
       <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <a href="#page_2" data-icon=forward  > Module B: ACTIVITE PRINCIPALE DU MENAGE </a> 
       </div><!-- /footer -->
      </div><!-- /page -->


    </template>
```

and the javascript (questionnaire.js) where `insertion` is the name of my `template` :

```
Mydata= new Meteor.Collection('mydata');
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.insertion.events ({
  'click  .submit': function () {
    Mydata.insert({
        identifiant: $('#identifiant').val(),
        nom_prenomCM: $('#nom_prenom_CM').val(),
        adresse: $('#adresse').val()
    }); 
  }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  }
```

The problem is that only generated id are seen using `Mydata.find().fetch()` from the web console.
What may be my mistake. I deploy the app online so that you can view it: http://herimanitra.meteor.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the id's in your html definition:

```
$('#identifiant').val(),
```

This statement looks for a html element with the id 'identifiant'. But in your html is no item with this id defined. Thats why your html should look like:

```
<input id="identifiant" autofocus maxlength="12" required placeholder="Entrez un nombre" name="identifiant"  type="number" />
<input id="adresse" name="adresse" type="text"/>
<input id="nom_prenom_CM" name="nom_prenom_CM" type="text" />
```

Another solution is to change your selector. You can for example get an inputfield with his name.

```
$('[name=adresse]').val();
```

Greets